# Select into comma separate with summary count?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server, how to select into **comma separate** with **summary count**?
I have data:

```
DECLARE @TB TABLE (ID INT, APP VARCHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @TB
VALUES
(1, 'A'),
(1, 'A'),
(1, 'B'),
(1, 'C'),
(1, 'C'),
(2, 'A'),
(2, 'B'),
(2, 'B')
```

[image]

I want to query result like this:

[image]

Comment: what is your MSSQL version?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server **2017** or above, you can use STRING_AGG as below-

```
DECLARE @TB TABLE (ID INT, APP VARCHAR(1))

INSERT INTO @TB
VALUES
(1, 'A'),
(1, 'A'),
(1, 'B'),
(1, 'C'),
(1, 'C'),
(2, 'A'),
(2, 'B'),
(2, 'B')

SELECT 
    ID, STRING_AGG (T, ',') 
FROM 
    (SELECT ID, APP + ' ' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR) T
     FROM @tb
     GROUP BY ID,APP) A
GROUP BY ID
```

For SQL Server 2016 or earlier-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2afe5e3cd5355c089d68b5672253ba63)

```
SELECT 
    ID,  
    abc = STUFF((SELECT ',' + T 
                 FROM 
                     (SELECT ID, APP + ' ' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR) T
                      FROM @tb
                      GROUP BY ID, APP) t1
                 WHERE t1.id = t2.id
                 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM
    @tb t2
GROUP BY 
    id;
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: Ohh... then you can check STUFF syntax in MSSQL.

Comment: @Sophairk, please check the script for MSSQL 2016 or earlier added in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do that easily in T-SQL. Have you considered having it as JSON instead?   It feels more KVP type data between the APP value and the count.

Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and see if that would work for you.

Comment: I don't understand, I am building a procedure for reporting.